# Efficient method to check whether the nearest prime has distance $d$ or more?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, algorithms, prime-gaps

Suppose, a prime $\ p\ $ is given.

> How can I check efficiently whether the distance to the nearest prime is $\ d\ $ or more , if $\ d\ $ is given ?

My approach is to start with $\ c=2\ $ and as long as $\ p-c\ $ and $\ p+c\ $ are both not prime increasing $\ c\ $ , the distance of the nearest prime is then $\ c\ $

Can I , apart from some trial divisions , accelerate the procedure somehow ?

Comment: noting p mod 6 didn't help ?

Comment: I did not notice a dependency between this residue and the distance $d$

Comment: 5 mod 6 going up forces distances 2 or 0 mod 6, down it forces 4 or 0 mod 6 unless 5 itself. 1 mod 6 forces, 4 and 0 up, and 2 and 0 down.

Comment: @Peter As [Roddy MacPhee](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/645636/roddy-macphee) has indicated, using a modulo can reduce the # of checks needed. More generally, this involves using [Wheel factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization) to allow you to avoid checking certain values which you definitely know are not prime.

Comment: If we wanted we could check $d-p<p-3$ or $d<\pi(p)$ Though at least one of these is conditional on a well known unproven conjecture.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee: I don't understand your last comment at all.

Comment: first one comes from Bertrands postulate for the next higher prime, ( and is also necessary for Goldbach), Second one Comes from Grimm's conjecture.